# UIPopoverController content appears too big

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uipopovercontroller

Im trying to present a `UIViewController` that contains a `UIWebView` inside a `UIPopOverController`.
The problem is, that the ViewController inside the popOverController "acts" as if it has an entire screen size so i get scroll indicators and scrolling instead of it just "surrendering" to the container size.

Any suggestions?

```
NSMutableArray *filesArr = AppDelegate.appContentManager.filesArray;
    BIDContent *cellContent = ((BIDContent *)[filesArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    BIDPreviewPopupViewController *popUpContent = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"previewPopup"];
    popUpContent.pageContent = cellContent;
    _popOverDisplay = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popUpContent];
    [_popOverDisplay setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2.0, self.view.frame.size.height/2.0)];
    popUpContent.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _popOverDisplay.popoverContentSize.width, _popOverDisplay.popoverContentSize.height);
    [_popOverDisplay presentPopoverFromRect:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:TRUE];
```

Answer (score 1):

Forgot about a "hidden" gem in the UIWebView - "scales page to fit". Once I turned this on, all was good!